# ASP.NET MVC is it possible to use ajax.beginform inside a partial view?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Layout -> View -> Partial View

**In the View:**

```
      <div class="col-md-8">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("_komentari", commentlist);}
            <div class="gap gap-small"></div>
            <div class="box bg-gray">
                <h3>@Res.commentwrite_title</h3>
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("postcomment", new { propertyid = Model.PublicID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "commentsarea", HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, null))
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>@Res.commentwrite_content</label>
                                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value='@Res.commentwrite_btn' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

**In the Partial View:**

```
    <div id="commentsarea">
    <ul class="booking-item-reviews list">
        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (Comment item in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="booking-item-review-person">
                                <a class="booking-item-review-person-avatar round" href="#">
                                    <img src="/assets/img/70x70.png" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Bubbles" />
                                </a>
                                <p class="booking-item-review-person-name">

                                    @if (item.UserId != null)
                                    {
                                        <a href='@Url.Action("details", "user", new { userid = item.User.PublicId })'>@item.User.Username</a>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <a href="#">Anonymous</a>
                                    }

                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="booking-item-review-content">
                                <p>
                                    @item.Content
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-small mt20">@item.DateOnMarket</p>

                                <p class="booking-item-review-rate">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("reportcomment", new { comment = item.PublicId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "reportscount", HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, null))
                    {
                                    <a id="submit_link" href="#">Spam?</a>
                                    <a class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down box-icon-inline round" href="#"></a>
                    }
    <b id="reportscount" class="text-color">@item.CommentReports.Count</b>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            }

        }
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a#submit_link').click(function () {
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

View

Both scripts for Ajax are always included in the Layout (I'm already using Ajax on other pages too). On the View page, when I add a new comment, it is added in the database and shows the updated list of comments via ajax. Everything works fine.

Partial View

But if I want to report the comment as spam, I have to click on the link inside the Partial View (#submit_link), and after reporting, inside the #reportscount part, I want to show the updated number of reports of that comment. The actionresults returns that number like Content(numberofreports.toString()). It works but I get the number in a blank page?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you don't. The main issue is that, for security reasons, `<script>` tags are ignored, when HTML is inserted into the DOM. Since the `Ajax.*` family of helpers work by inserting `<script>` tags in place, when you return the partial via AJAX, those will not be present. It's better if you only include the HTML contents of the form in the partial, and not the form itself.

Comment: Oh, thanks! So, I should use Layout - View - PartialView - PartialView? Is that possible?